# jenkins not failling when junit beforeclass setup method failing

Tags: junit, jenkins

when @beforeclass executes assertion failure , it is not causing test result to fail in jenkins. how can I change this to failure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a post build step to check the junit test results. We use "Publish JUnit test result report" and add the location where the results output (xml files) are stored.